# How can I tell sed to stop after the matching word?

Tags: bash, sed

I'm currently trying to update some strings and expand them by an ID.

The problem is, that my `sed` finds more matches than I want it to, yet I understand why it is doing that.

I got different lines, e.g.:

- LogInventory
- LogInventory Error
- LogInventory Version

The problem is, that when I let `sed` find "**LogInventory**" and expand the search result by the ID (8), then I get the following result:

- LogInventory (8)
- LogInventory (8) Error
- LogInventory (8) Version

How can I tell `sed` to stop after the matching word and not to pay attention to what follows on the same line. The `sed` command can stop after the first match and doesn't have to keep looking for a further match.

Each string is in a new line.

This is what I tried so far .. I assume this would word, if I got string like "**LogInventory**" and "**LogInventoryError**"..

```
    sed -i 's/\<ASP Inventory\>/ASP Inventory (8)/g' $file
```

Comment: `stop after the matching word` - which word? Like, you want to stop after the first match? Ie. quit sed script after the line with a match is found? What is the result you want to have?

Comment: @KamilCuk .. exactly! If the sed-command finds the "LogInventory" it can stop at exactly this point and doesn't have to keep looking for other entries!

Comment: By "stop" you mean still output all the lines after the matched string or by "stop" you mean just don't output anything else? Still what is your expected output? Why your `sed` matches `ASP Inventory`, yet your sample file contains `LogInventory`? And please post expected output for the sample input file you posted.

Comment: The sed command should look into the given file, look for "x", expand it to "x (x)" and then end.

Comment: @shas replied the needed help! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your example you have use `$` while matching string

```
sed -i 's/ASP Inventory$/ASP Inventory (8)/g' $file
```

**Output**

```
ASP Inventory (8)
ASP Inventory Error
ASP Inventory Version
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @shas ! It worked just as I wanted it to do! :)

Comment: @MichaelK Accept my Answer